# Oracle Global constant or variable?

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

Is there a way to declare a global variable or constant that could be used in the DECLARE section of a Block and from other places such as C#?

I have several scripts that set different states on a log table depending on the success of their operation.
Such us:

```
UPDATE LOG_TABLE SET  STATUS = ''success' WHERE OBJECT_ID = :object_id
```

Also we have a C# application that performs certain operations that can't be done from Oracle. And this application also sets a STATUS according the success of its operations.

Since some of the Status are used in several scripts and in C# I would like to define them in only one place. And then access and use them from everywhere else.

**Is there a way I could declare something similar to a Global Constant** that could later be used in a PL/SQL block like this:

```
GLOBAL ORACLE CONSTANT=> MY_CONSTANT

DECLARE
  my_update_script VARCHAR2(300) := 'UPDATE LOG_TABLE SET  STATUS = '''|| MY_CONSTANT ||''' WHERE OBJECT_ID = :object_id;
```

And also be able to use it from C#?

Comment: Use a `Context variable`. It will have the same value globally across all the sessions.

Comment: Define a constant in a package spec. Or create a function returning a constant (don't know about the efficiency of the latter though).

Comment: @LalitKumarB I don't know much about Context variable, but from what I am reading, if I create a Global Application Context it would be available for the entire Database and all users, am I correct?

Comment: @collapsar I am not sure what do you mean by defining a constant in a package spec. Most of my scripts are Anonymous Blocks and are not inside a Package. Are you suggesting to create a package that contains my scripts and so they share a constant? Can a function be used in the Declare section of a block as I illustrated as desirable behavior?

Comment: I meant to create a package to contain your constants. This would establish a global context so that you can refer to your constants as `package.constant_n`.

Comment: @Dzyann, yes, correct.

Comment: @collapsar - In the end I decided using a package like you suggested. I think is the option most suited for my needs. I had a package with some utils required for the whole process, so it was the ideal place to put the constants. Thanks for your suggestions!

Comment: @collapsar - if you want to post it as the answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Best way to create a global variable will be to create it inside a package.

Like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE PKG_PARAM AS
PROCEDURE SET_MY_CONSTANT (P_MY_CONSTANT IN VARCHAR2);
MY_CONSTANT VARCHAR2 (30);
END PKG_PARAM;
```

You can use it like

```
my_update_script VARCHAR2(300) := 'UPDATE LOG_TABLE SET  STATUS = '''|| PKG_PARAM.MY_CONSTANT ||''' WHERE OBJECT_ID = :object_id;
```

Also you can change value for your variable  by creating a procedure inside your package as:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY PKG_PARAM AS
PROCEDURE SET_MY_CONSTANT (P_MY_CONSTANT IN VARCHAR2)
IS
BEGIN
MY_CONSTANT := P_MY_CONSTANT;
END;
END PKG_PARAM;
```

and then executing your procedure:

```
EXEC PKG_PARAM.SET_MY_CONSTANT('ASIA');
```